# How to tell Template where to load files from?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to store some templates in the database for custom rendering. I create a `Template` object with the string coming from the database and then I use the `render` method. So far so good.

Now I would like to be able to use the *extension* mechanism to load a template from another one with the `{% extends %}` tag so that even the base template could be loaded from the database. I realized that the extension mechanism works and uses the global configuration given in settings. So I'm able to extend from a file from my template loaders. I can also add my custom loader to look for data source in the database. However I would like my TemplateLoader to know what database object was the source of the first template, and look for base files depending on that.

I would expect a hook into the Template object to specify custom TemplateLoaders instead of global ones. I've looked into documentation and source files, but failed to find such an hook.

Any hint?

** CLARIFICATION **
Since I dind' get an answer, I try to clarify the question. Suppose I have a template to render some kind of objects of my database. This template uses an {% extends "base.html" %} to load the skeleton file with the base layout of the site. Suppose now that for some of these objects (based for example on an attribute in the object) I want to modify the base file (not the template!). How do I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe one should use jinja instead of django templates

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add feature to load you templates from databases with: http://django-dbtemplates.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

Comment: I known how to load templates from the database. However I'm forced to always give the same template when, for example, "base.html" is requested. I would like to give different files, depending on the file being processed.